# Are non-Hindus allowed inside Tirumala Veṅkaṭēśwara Temple? Do they need to sign a waiver?

Tags: temple, vaishnavism, other-religions, venkateshwara, tirupati

1. Are non-Hindus allowed inside [Tirumala Veṅkaṭēśwara Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara_Temple,_Tirumala)?
2. I heard that for a non-Hindu to enter the temple, they need to sign a waiver. Is this true? Also, is it a recent development or restriction?
3. If so, what exactly does this waiver say or look like?

---

<sub>Note:</sub> 
<sub>1. This is related to but not a duplicate of: [Why are non-Hindus not allowed inside temples?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7121)</sub>
<sub>2. I'm looking for credible sources of information, so, no Wikipedia, Quora.com or random blogs in answers please.</sub>
<sub>3. News articles are ok to cite in your answers provided they actually interviewed [TTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirumala_Tirupati_Devasthanams) management on this.</sub>

Comment: This is because non Hindus (mostly Foreigners) are just visiting it as tourist place without showing any respect to Venkateswara. Also, a Christian made a video on Tirumala claiming that Hindus are worshipping just a rock. This Video uploaded to Youtube angered many Hindus and TTD took these measures to curb these kind of immature acts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I read in an article which says TTD had this waiver or declaration in place for 50 yrs or so .. not sure. When was this video by a Christian made?

Comment: Rules may have changed more recently, but I remember 10 or 15 years ago we had white tourists standing behind us in line at Tirupati.  They didn't even know they were in a Hindu temple, they just thought it was some kind of tourist attraction due to the massive lines.  But after they saw the Venkateshwara statue, they were filled with such incredible feelings that they told us "Whatever religion venerates that statue must be the correct religion.  Where can we sign up?"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Non Hindus are allowed inside the Tirumala Veṅkaṭēśwara Temple. They need to sign a waiver that they have faith in Lord Veṅkaṭēśwara.

This is not a religious restriction. This was passed by the Government of Andhra Pradesh in the April 1990. This had been in vogue for several decades. It was only followed as a tradition and not a rule by only those who volunteered to give the declaration.  Now, TTD has made it compulsory for non Hindus to sign a waiver that they have faith in Veṅkaṭēśwara Temple. Preaching other religions in Tirumala especially in the temple premises is illegal.

From a news article from [India Today](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/non-hindus-to-sign-faith-form-to-enter-tirumala-temple-in-andhra-pradesh/1/210621.html),

> According to TTD joint executive officer K S Srinivasa Raju, non-Hindus must necessarily sign the declaration form at the Vaikuntam queue complex before having the darshan of the Lord. Though the practice had been in vogue for several decades, it was only followed as a tradition and not a rule by only those who volunteered to give the declaration.
>
> Now, **the TTD authorities have made it compulsory as per the government order (GO MS No. 311 of AP Revenue Endowments-1) under Rule no. 16**. "It is now a mandatory rule for all those belonging to various faiths other than Hinduism to sign a declaration form before entering the hill temple stating that they have faith in the presiding deity," Raju said.

[image]

<sup>Image Courtesy : [Gotirupati](https://gotirupati.com/admission-of-non-hindus/)</sup>

The text in the above image says that the Government order was passed on 09 April 1990. IT might have been there even before this but the devotees used to sign voluntarily.

The rule holds for the temples maintained by Tirumala Tirupati Devasthanams(TTD).

The waivers are available at all sub-enquiry offices, besides the Pushkar and JEO's office at Tirumala.

> For the convenience of devotees, the declaration forms would be available at all sub-enquiry offices, besides the Peshkar and JEO's office.